# Arduino TFT and UTFT library

Tags: arduino

I try to test a [3.2"inch TFT LCD module](http://www.ebay.pl/itm/271201097446?ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWNX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649) (with an SSD1289 controller, and ADS7843 compatible touch panel controller) with the library [UTFT](http://www.henningkarlsen.com/electronics/library.php?id=51).

This library supports TFT (listed in PDF) and [Arduino Leonardo](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardLeonardo).

After connecting according to the description and running a test application from this library nothing happens. I mean, the TFT part is working, but it is light blue and there are no graphs from the example code.

1. How to check the TFT revision (REBA or REVB)?
2. How do I connect it? I'm not sure about the below connections.
   TFT -> Leonardo

   ```
   LED_A -> 5&nbsp;V
   3.3&nbsp;V -> 3.3&nbsp;V
   RD -> 3.3&nbsp;V
   ```
3. How do I initialise this library and get it working?

I tried with:

```
UTFT myGLCD(ELEE32_REVB,19,18,17,16);
UTFT myGLCD(ELEE32_REVB,A5,A4,A3,A2);
UTFT myGLCD(ELEE32_REVB,A1,A2,A0,99);
UTFT myGLCD(ELEE32_REVA,A1,A2,A0,A3, A5);
```

I always get the same effects, light blue screen and no graphs from the example code.

Answer (score 1):

use the `SSD1289` controller:

```
UTFT myGLCD(SSD1289,...);
```

as documented in the UTFT library examples:

```
// Remember to change the model parameter to suit your display module!
//UTFT myGLCD(ITDB32S,A5,A4,A3,A2);
UTFT myGLCD(SSD1289,38,39,40,41);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the backlight is working, but nothing else.   I have a similar module, but it plugs into an interface card which then plugs into a MEGA.

The LED_A signal is the same as LED_BL (A= anode of the backlight LEDs, BL=Backlight, I think).  RD is the "read" signal -- you never will read from the LCD, so it needs to be pulled up to digital high -- seems like for the Leonardo this will be 5V, assuming that the other digital pins are 5V.

I would recommend the "REVB" which really means 8 bit mode. So, if you've hooked it up as recommended in the UTFT file "UTFT_Requirements.pdf", you should use:

UTFT myGLCD(ELEE32_REVB,A5,A4,A3,A2);

Be sure to hook up the DB0-DB7 as detailed in green on page 4.

I hope that helps!